# Countable elementary sub-structure of the automorphism group of the binary rooted tree

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be the automorphism group of the binary rooted tree.

The [downward Löwenheim-Skolem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) theorem states that G has a countable elementary sub-structure.

My question is whether such sub-structure is explicitly known?

([Original question was in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723075/countable-elementary-sub-structure-of-the-automorphism-group-of-the-binary-roote))

Comment: Is there an explicit description of the group or its first-order theory?

Comment: @Emil: I think this group has a pretty explicit description as a pro-$p$ group with $p=2$, by mapping it onto the automorphisms groups of the $n$-neighborhoods of the root, for all integers $n \ge 1$.

Comment: I don't know much about the first-order theory of that group, but the set of computable automorphisms seems extremely likely to be an elementary substructure.